# DataGridColumn binding fail

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid

This is my `DataGrid`;

```
    <DataGrid Visibility="Visible"
        Grid.Row="1"
        SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader"
        Name="dataGrid"
        SelectionMode="Single"
        ItemsSource="{Binding collcection}">
        <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Command="Copy" Click="MenuItem_Click_1"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Select">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox 
                            x:Name="cbRunRobot"
                            IsChecked="{Binding Value}"
                            Width="60"
                            Height="25"
                            Checked="cbRunRobot_Checked"
                            Unchecked="cbRunRobot_Unchecked"
                            Margin="25,0,0,0" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

View Model:

```
list<MyData> collcection;
public class MyData
{
   public string Name;
   public string Id;
}
```

I try to add this `Column`:

```
<DataGridColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" Width="180"/>
```

And got this errors:

Error   1   The type "DataGridColumn" is abstract and must include an explicit value.

Error   2   The member "Binding" is not recognized or is not accessible.

Comment: Can you add your full DataGrid xaml. Do you have the columns defined within the <DataGrid.Columns>?

Answer (score 1):

`DataGridColumn` is an abstract class which means it cannot be instantiated. The same applies to `DataGridBoundColumn`.

You're choices are:

- `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` for boolean values
- `DataGridComboBoxColumn` for enumerable values
- `DataGridHyperlinkColumn` for Uri values
- `DataGridTemplateColumn` to show any types of data by defining your own cell template
- `DataGridTextColumn` to show text values

It looks like `DataGridTextColumn`  is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I can suggest you the next:

1. Bind to ObservableCollection instead the list.
2. Make your MyData model to implement InotifyPropertyChanged.
3. Make each binding involved property in MyData model to fire OnPropertyChanged event.
4. Here is the link to the working example:[How to Display and select items in a Datagrid ComboBox with WPF C#, using MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33254765/how-to-display-and-select-items-in-a-datagrid-combobox-with-wpf-c-using-mvvm/33265495#33265495).

regards,