# Boolean dataGridComboBoxColumn display Yes/No

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have a dataGrid bound with a Collection. For two columns (A and B), the data are 1 or 0.
Instead, I would like to display Yes or No in a comboBoxColumn and of course if 'yes' is selected 1 is saved and 0 for 'no'.

How can I do that?

## **View**

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="id" Binding="{Binding idproduct, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ref Supplier" Binding="{Binding refsup, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding description, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Unit"  
                                                        ItemsSource="{Binding Collection, Source={StaticResource unit}}"
                                                        DisplayMemberPath="unit1" 
                                                        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding unit}" 
                                                        SelectedValuePath="idunit"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price/MOQ" Binding="{Binding priceMOQ, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="A" Binding="{Binding A, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="B" Binding="{Binding B, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
   </DataGrid>
```

## **ViewModel**

```
public class ProductViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {


        public Context ctx = new Context();

        private ObservableCollection<product> collection;

        public ObservableCollection<product> Collection
        {
            get
            {
                if (collection == null)
                {
                    Get();
                }
                return collection;
            }
            set
            {
                collection = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Collection");
            }
        }

        #region "Command"

    }
```

## **Model**

```
public partial class product
    {
        public int idproduct { get; set; }
        public string refsup { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> unit { get; set; }
        public sbyte larot { get; set; }
        public sbyte lasand { get; set; }


        public virtual foodSupplier foodSupplier { get; set; }
        public virtual unit unit1 { get; set; }
    }
```

## **Update**

I tried the two ways, but it doesn't work.

```
<Page.Resources>
        <hlp:YesNoToBooleanConverter x:Key="YesNoToConverter" />
</Page.Resources>

<DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding A}"
                                          SelectedValue="{Binding A}">
                                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock Name="TextBlock" Text="No" />
                                            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="1">
                                                    <Setter TargetName="TextBlock" Property="Text" Value="Yes" />
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                </ComboBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding B}"
                                          SelectedValue="{Binding B}">
                                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource YesNoToConverter}}" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                </ComboBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>



 public class YesNoToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
  {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            byte inValue = System.Convert.ToByte(value);
            string outValue = (inValue == 1) ? "Yes" : "No";
            return outValue;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {

            switch (value.ToString().Trim().ToLower())
            {
                case "yes":
                    return 1;
                case "no":
                    return 0;
                default:
                    return 0;
            }
        }
  }
```

Comment: Can you share your Product model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can suggest you the next exact solution  of this problem. Please check this out.
 1. ComboBox XAML code:

```
 <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="ActivityStatus" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding IsActive, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="system:Boolean">
                    <system:Boolean>True</system:Boolean>
                    <system:Boolean>False</system:Boolean>
                </x:Array>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource>
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

you ca see the whole solution on this stack overflow query link:
[How to Display and select items in a Datagrid ComboBox with WPF C#, using MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33254765/how-to-display-and-select-items-in-a-datagrid-combobox-with-wpf-c-using-mvvm/33265495#33265495).

regards,